# Tkinter colorchooser.askcolor() bug

Tags: python, function, tkinter, module

I'm learning Tkinter and I used for the very first time this module: colorchooser, but I started to get a bug that even though I don't import this module will appear on my program.

This is the code I was using:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")


def color():
my_color = colorchooser.askcolor()



my_button = Button(root, text="Pick A Color", command=color).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The weirdest thing is after this, for every file in my computer that has the Tkinter imported, this colorchooser.askcolor() will appear. At first, I thought it was something wrong with VS code, but then I ran it on Terminal and Pycharm and it was the same.

Does anyone know why is this happening or has experienced this bug before with this module or another one? I restarted the computer as well but the issue remains.

Comment: did you named a file `tkinter.py` and call the `colorchooser` in it?

Comment: Also did you note that `my_button` becomes `None` instead of a reference to your `Button`. Split the constructor from the geometry method to avoid that.

Comment: No, I didn't. This function appears even if I create a new file from scratch.

Comment: You have never named a file `tkinter.py` ? Not just the currently used one.

Comment: No, bro. Never. This bug started with a file named:  49-Color-Picker.py